# Is there a way to know what platform will be used for a binary install on a system?

Tags: pip

When you do a pip install and there is a binary wheel available, pip intelligently selects apparently the most compatible binary version for that platform…

You can override or select the platform of choice by using the --platform keyword.

What I want to know if there is a straightforward way to get pip to output, ideally in order of preference, what binary versions it would use first